# why explicit type casting required from double to float but not from int to byte?

Tags: java, casting

Consider following statement:

`byte by = 5;     //works fine`

literal '5' is of type int and small enough to fit into a variable of type byte. Compiler does the implicit type casting here (from int to byte).

Now consider following scenario:

```
float fl = 5.5;    //compilation error
```

literal '5.5' is of type double, also small enough to fit into a variable of 
type float. Why do we need to explicitly type cast like this:

```
float fl = (float) 5.5;   //works fine
```

Why compiler is not doing the casting for us in case of floating points?

Comment: and also long to int needs explicit conversion!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the integer version, the compiler knows that *all* the data in the number `5` can be stored in a `byte`. No information is lost. That's not always true for floating point values. For example, `0.1f` isn't equal to `0.1d`.

Now for the example, you've given, the decimal value 5.5 *is* exactly represented in both `float` and `double`, so you could argue that in that case, no information is lost - but it would be pretty odd for the language specification to have to make this valid:

```
float f = 5.5;
```

but this invalid:

```
float f = 5.6;
```

The language specification is happy to talk about whether a number fits within the range of `float`/`double` (although even *that* isn't as simple as you might expect) but when it comes to whether a literal can be exactly represented, I don't think it *ever* goes into detail.

Comment: plus one, in short `5.1 != 5.1f` and `5.1 - 5.1f` == `9.536743128535363E-8`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Could you elaborate your comment?

Comment: @maximus335 `5.1` uses a 64-bit value and approximates 5.1 more accurately than `5.1f` which only uses a 32-bit.  This means that while the value appear similar they are not the same. c.f. 5.5 is represented precisely in `double` and `float` which is why I picked a different value. ;)

Comment: If I were designing a language, I would allow floating-point literals to include a suffix indicating what degree of precision was expected.  If an `pf` suffix indicates "precise float", then the value `1111111.1xf` would be rejected, but `111111.125xf` would be accepted.  Sometimes a programmer intends for a compiler to use the closest representable value to some number, and sometimes a programmer intends a compiler to use an exact number and would want to know if it can't.  I wish languages would let programmers indicate such intentions.

Answer (score 3):

The easy answer is, because the specification says so (compile-time constants of type integer can be assigned to smaller types as long as they fit).

With floating-point however, there is not so much determining whether the constant fits, but rather the loss of precision that comes along with it. E.g. assigning 1.23456789123 to a double is fine, but to a float is not. It's not so obvious *why*, in this case, though, at least to some programmers. I'd definitely count it as a surprise when *some* floating-point constants work while others won't and the reason isn't as clear as with integral types (where the limits are often second nature to most).

Note that even with doubles there sometimes is lost information. You can make your constants as precise as you want, but you won't always get the exact value you stated in the variable.

Comment: If the standard had allowed double literals to be assigned to `float` values, the behavior would IMHO have been less surprising than e.g. `double oneTenthKindaSorta = 1.0f/10.0f;` or `long whatsThis = Math.round(123456789012345L);` [any predictions for those]?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Jon, However, I would like to add that

```
byte by = 5;     //works fine until the number is less than 128
```

This is because one byte can only hold upto -128 to 127. Once you will try to enter number above 127, you will get the same error like you get when storing double value into float.

```
byte by =  128; //compilation error
```

So for agreeing the lost of the conversion data, you need to perform the explicit conversion.

```
byte by = (byte) 128; // work fine
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most significant reason that Java makes allowance for implicit narrowing conversions of literals of type `int` to `short` and `byte`, but does not do so for conversions of literal `double` values to `float` is that Java includes `float` literals, but does not allow literals of types `byte` and `short`.

Personally, I really dislike Java's numerical conversion rules, but the allowance for storing integer constants to `short` and `byte` makes those types at least somewhat bearable.