# Auto conversion issue in Java

Tags: java, primitive-types

I am concerned with dealing with primitive types in Java, especially with the auto conversion.

My question is:

**Why does the auto conversion works for `byte` and `int`, but not for `float` and `double`?**

Take a look at the code:

If I write

```
byte b = 100;
```

the compiler first has an `int` of value `100` and converts it to a `byte`, which fits, because the domain of `byte` is `[-128, 127]`.

That's why

```
byte b = 128;
```

does not work. The compiler says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte`.

But: The same approach to `float` and `double` it does not work!

If I try

```
float f = 1.5;
```

the compiler says: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to  float`, although `1.5` is within the domain of float (`float f = 1.5f;` works very fine).

Comment: Without the "f", the default type of 1.5 is double.

Comment: Hope this SO answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361456/why-explicit-type-casting-required-from-double-to-float-but-not-from-int-to-byte

Comment: By converting from `double` to `float` you are losing accuracy, so the compiler will not do it for you automatically. You need to explicitly tell it that you want a float: `float f = 1.5F;`